# problem drag and drop question to add text in a text area

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

i develop my code to drag and drop items in a text area, but i have to problems that  don't know how to fixed.

First when you get the element in the drag take alot of space i only need the text, no more, no less.

Second i can't clean the text at consequence, always append data all the time, i need to clean and only add the current object.

Third how can i put in bold the text when it's dropped in the textarea?? any ideas. Thanks

[see my code](http://jsfiddle.net/kWAtJ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that ?

[***Click Here***](http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/kWAtJ/4/)

Comment: @Alexander Corotchi closed but i in bold only the item the i left dropped. if i type  doesn't have to be bold. And well the problem the if you erase the data when you drop again, appears all the info dispite the be erased

Comment: @Alexander Corotchi it's good but when i type direct into the textarea should by without bold.

Comment: @Alexander Corotchi also have the problem when you erased,  the data and drag another item apper's all the others items dragged.

Comment: so, in this case, I will suggest not to use textarea box, but a div , I am amusing we cannot add HTML tags in textarea form

Comment: @Alexander Corotchi i had thought about it but the problem it's how i can let to the user to write in a div??

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think i am bit late, but you can find the solution at below link,

```
[Have a look]: http://jsfiddle.net/ravindrakhokharia/gGAhp
```

thanks